# How can I hide the commands I type in a server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

So on a minecraft server, when I type /gamemode creative or something, then how can I make so it doesn't show that I run the command in chat.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By using the `/gamerule`[command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/gamerule).

---

The command:

`/gamerule sendCommandFeedback false`

will affect "whether the feedback from commands executed by a player should show up in chat."